# How do I generate a minimal wasm file with Rust?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I can generate a fairly minimal (203 bytes) wasm file from the following C code by running `emcc -O3 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o sum.wasm sum.c`.

```c
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Disassembled output:

```
(module
 (type $0 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
 ... trim 9 lines ...
 (export "_sum" (func $0))
 (func $0 (type $0) (param $var$0 i32) (param $var$1 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.add
   (get_local $var$1)
   (get_local $var$0)
  )   
 )   
 ... trim 17 lines ...
)
```

But given the following Rust code

```
pub fn main() {}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn sum(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
```

I cannot seem to produce anything similar.

`rustc -O --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten sum.rs` works but gives me an 85k wasm file and a 128k js file.

I've tried exporting `EMMAKEN_CFLAGS='-s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1'` but that gives me a number of warnings like

> Input file "/tmp/.../rust.metadata.bin" exists but was not an LLVM bitcode file suitable for Emscripten. Perhaps accidentally mixing native built object files with Emscripten?

and then fails to link.

My Rust version is `1.22.0-nightly (c6884b12d 2017-09-30)` and my emcc version is `1.37.21`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hah, a week of searching and I find nothing. Then minutes after posting this question I find [this](https://gist.github.com/LukasKalbertodt/821ab8b85a25f4c54544cc43bed2c39f) which may answer it. Will report back once I test it out.

Comment: In [this file](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0defa208dcb5a0f3c1ca5bc4df7acf52759ece44/src/librustc_back/target/wasm32_unknown_emscripten.rs) pretty much everything about Rust's emscripten target is defined. And [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b2f67c8d5676d13d83523316ac95a7056dbd19c6/src/librustc_back/target/mod.rs), the comment says that one can add targets by writing a JSON file (without recompiling rustc!). So you could try that to add a custom target which passes the `SIDE_MODULE` flag to emcc. I would write a proper answer, but I don't have time right now. Sorry :<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` target, you're using an Emscripten-based compiler toolchain. Emscripten adds quite a bit of additional runtime code into the wasm module, as well as additional JavaScript code for integrating with this at runtime. As you have also observed, Emscripten can compile with a `SIDE_MODULE` option that removes the vast majority of this runtime code. This reduces the wasm binary size, but means that you must handle things such as binding complex types yourself.

Very recently (Nov, 2017) a new [wasm32-unknown-unknown target was added to Rust](https://www.hellorust.com/news/native-wasm-target.html), which uses the LLVM backend (rather than Emscripten and its fastcomp fork), resulting in a minimal output.

This target can be used as described in the [setup guide](https://www.hellorust.com/setup/wasm-target/):

```
rustup update
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
rustc +nightly --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O hello.rs
```

Comment: I've just spotted, there's a toolkit built around this concept https://github.com/dcodeIO/webassembly

Comment: @Shepmaster fair point - I've completely re-written the answer